# XCB how to get value of a atom

Tags: c, x11, xorg, window-managers, xcb

I'm writing a small system info ("*fetch") program (in C) and I want to get the name of the WM, only problem is that the documentation of XCB is rather lacking and Xlib has really terrible one. So I can't figure it out on my own.

I know that the atom: `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK` of the root window should have a ID of the WM, and the WM should set it's `_NET_WM_NAME` to it's name. But I do not know how to even get it's id.

The only thing I know for sure is how to get the root window. But there just simply isn't any documentation for the rest, or (more likely) I have been using wrong search terms...

Comment: [`xcb_intern_atom()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/xcb_intern_atom.3.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

static xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t intern(xcb_connection_t *c, const char *name) {
    return xcb_intern_atom(c, 0, strlen(name), name);
}

int main() {
    // TODO: Any kind of error handling. This is just the happy path.

    xcb_connection_t *c = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    xcb_screen_t *s = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(c)).data;
    xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t wm_name_cookie = intern(c, "_NET_WM_NAME");
    xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t wm_check_cookie = intern(c, "_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK");
    xcb_intern_atom_reply_t *wm_name = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, wm_name_cookie, NULL);
    xcb_intern_atom_reply_t *wm_check = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, wm_check_cookie, NULL);

    xcb_get_property_reply_t *wm_name_value = xcb_get_property_reply(c,
            xcb_get_property(c, 0, s->root, wm_name->atom, XCB_GET_PROPERTY_TYPE_ANY, 0, ~0),
            NULL);
    xcb_get_property_reply_t *wm_check_value = xcb_get_property_reply(c,
            xcb_get_property(c, 0, s->root, wm_check->atom, XCB_ATOM_WINDOW, 0, ~0),
            NULL);

    printf("%.*s\n", xcb_get_property_value_length(wm_name_value),
            (char*) xcb_get_property_value(wm_name_value));
    printf("0x%"PRIx32"\n", *(xcb_window_t*) xcb_get_property_value(wm_check_value));

    free(wm_name_value);
    free(wm_check_value);
    free(wm_name);
    free(wm_check);

    return 0;
}
```

To check the above, here is my experiment comparing against a "known good" program:

```
$ gcc t.c -O2 -Wall -Wextra -lxcb && ./a.out ; echo ; xprop -root | grep -E '(_NET_WM_NAME|SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK)\('
i3
0x800063

_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "i3"
_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK(WINDOW): window id # 0x800063
```

Comment: I figured out something simmilar, but the problem is that I can't get the window id of the WM from `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK`. I used the same code for it, but it returns something different each time I run it...

Comment: *Why* do you want to get the window ID of the window in `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK`? But okay, I will update my answer.